# Работа с CheckBox в WPF. Как с помощью CheckBox выключать музыку или метод, в котором она запускается?

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, mediaplayer

В моём приложении по окончании таймера играет музыка. **Картинка его в самом низу.**

Они находятся(их две для каждого таймера отдельно) в методах:

```
private void MusicEndWork()
            {
                    Ew = new MediaPlayer();
                    Ew.Open(new Uri(@"C:\Users\grrek\source\repos\WpfApppp\WpfApppp\Res\EndWorkSound.wav", UriKind.Absolute));
                    Ew.Play();
            }

private void MusicEndBreak()
        {
                Eb = new MediaPlayer();
                Eb.Open(new Uri(@"C:\Users\grrek\source\repos\WpfApppp\WpfApppp\Res\EndBreakSound.wav", UriKind.Absolute));
                Eb.Play();
        }
```

Мой метод решения задачи был такой, я ставил условия в начле метода , если переменная A равна true, делаем код в методе, false, не делаем. По умолчанию я задавал переменной A = true, а уже в событиях(у меня их было четыре, для двух чек боксов на каждое состояние отмечено\не отмечено) менял её значение.

Но что-то не сработало.

Вот моё событие:

Это уже другой класс, поэтому в самом начале его я создаю экземпляр главного окна:

```
MainWindow main = new MainWindow();

        private void CheckBoxWork(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            main.proverkaMusicStart = false;
        }

        private void CheckBoxEnd(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            main.proverkaMusicEnd = false;
        }

        private void CheckBoxWorkUN(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            main.proverkaMusicStart = true;
        }

        private void CheckBoxEndUN(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            main.proverkaMusicEnd = true;
        }
```

1. Вопрос, можно ли как-то проще реализовать мою задачу?
2. Можно ли сделать disable метода?
3. Почему мой вариант не работает?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Можно вот так, по обработчику на событие `Checked` для каждого чекбокса.

```csharp
private void CheckBoxWork(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    main.proverkaMusicStart = (sender as CheckBox)?.IsChecked ?? false;
}
```

В этом случае, если чекбокс отмечен, будет `true` если не отмечен или `null` (такое тоже бывает), будет `false`.

2) Что такое `disable` метода?

3) Вам не нужно создавать экземпляр главного окна (зачем вам 2 экземпляра окна?), его можно получить из приложения

```csharp
MainWindow main = Application.Current.MainWindow as MainWindow;
```

Comment: 2) Disable метода - это отключение метода, к примеру вы его вызываете, он не вызывается, я это выдумал. НО а может всё же так можно делать в C#?
3) Что значит, можно получить из приложения? И почему создание второго экземпляра - неверный подход? Что вообще такое этот экземпляр главного окна?

Comment: 2) заведите переменную `bool isDisabled` присвойте ей значение, в методе в начале напишите `if (isDisabled) return`. При значении переменной `true` произойдет выход из метода.

Comment: @Grek 3) экземпляр - это объект, для окна - это само окно, оно на экране. Если создать еще один экземпля окна - у вас будет 2 окна на экране, одинаковых. И у каждого свои собственные методы и свойства.

Comment: @Grek вот, посмотрите эти [веселые видео](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLuGqgO5WmeGPTZqDHZDIum3h7HnfBfzmZ), в них много для вас полезного. И вам надо бы узнать, что такое Объектно Ориентированное Программирование. Без этих знаний вам будет тяжело понять, как и что работает.

Comment: Спасибо большое, всё работает.